# xdebug remote: can I execute php code or change variables?

Tags: php, sublimetext2, xdebug

Is it possible to execute arbitrary PHP code or at least change the value of variables during a breakpoint using xdebug's remote debugging? I'm using the Sublime Text 2 plugin [SublimeXDebug](https://github.com/Kindari/SublimeXdebug).

Answer (score 6):

Xdebug supports modifying variables through the DBGp protocol. It can also execute (eval) code. Some IDEs, like Komodo and PhpStorm allow you to change the values through the IDE. It is very likely that others, such as SublimeXdebug doesn't allow that.

A reference to the DBGp command property_set is at: http://www.xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php#property-get-property-set-property-value
A reference for eval is at: http://www.xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php#eval

Comment: never did that. are you sure that this is possible with *PHP* and is not only possible with the protocol?

Comment: Thx for teaching me. (will delete my answer). Note that I usually not use xdebug for remote debugging, but the function traces are *really* nice as well as profiling. thanks for this! :)  Btw, not using remote debugging is a common illness of PHP developers. Maybe I should use it more often ....